# Not sure where 'None' is coming from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggling with the 'None' I get from my inputs. It seems to be working just fine for what I'm trying to do(any input or ideas appreciated though). However the extra 'None' is bugging me without being able to pinpoint why it's doing that. Please help me find exactly where the issue is? I'm also learning in my spare time, please forgive my mistakes.

```
class Player:

    

    def __init__(self, name, element, attack, defence, hp, mp, gold):
        self.name = name
        self.element = element
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.hp = hp
        self.mp = mp
        self.gold = gold




class Displays():
    def __init__(self, name, heading, pageOptions):
        self.name = name
        self.heading = heading
        self.pageOptions = pageOptions

    def printPage(self):
        print('  *** ' + self.heading + ' ***  ')
        print(self.name)
        for key in self.pageOptions:
            print(' ', key, self.pageOptions[key]['name'])

    def pageInput(self):
        pInput = int(input('Num: '))
        if pInput in self.pageOptions:
            print(self.pageOptions[pInput]['entry']())
        else:
            print('Invalid')


class Intros(Displays):
    pass

def Stats():
    print(f'_{P.name} Stats_')
    print()
    print(f'Element - {P.element}')
    print(f'Attack - {P.attack}')
    print(f'Defence - {P.defence}')
    print(f'Health - {P.hp}')
    print(f'Mana - {P.mp}')
    print(f'Gold - {P.gold}')

    print()


def Rename():
    print(f'What would you like to change your name to {P.name}?')
    P.name = input('Letters and numbers only-> ')
    print(f'Your name has been changed to {P.name}.')
    
def Exit():
    print('Working Exit')
    exit()

def Menu():
    print('Working menu')
    


def Settings():
    print('Working settings')


def Home():
    print('Working home')


def Element():
        print()
        print(f'Hi {P.name}, your current element is {P.element}.')
        print()
        print("What would you like to change it to?")
        print()
        for key, value in elements.items():
                print(f"{key}) {value}")

        eleInp = input("---> ")
        if eleInp in elements.keys():
            P.element = elements[eleInp]
            print(f'You have successfully changed your element to {P.element}.')

        else:
            print("Invalid")



intro1 = Intros('Intro Page', 'Page One',
                {
                    1: {'name': 'Character Stats', 'entry': Stats},
                    2: {'name': 'Rename Character', 'entry': Rename},
                    3: {'name': 'Exit', 'entry': Exit},
                    4: {'name': 'Home', 'entry': Home},
                    5: {'name': 'Change Element', 'entry': Element}

                })

intro2 = Intros('Second', 'Second Screen',
                {
                    1: {'name': 'Menu', 'entry': Menu},
                    2: {'name': 'Settings', 'entry': Settings},
                    3: {'name': 'Home', 'entry': Home}
                })



elements = { '1': "Fire", '2': "Water", '3': "Earth", '4': "Air", '5': "Lightning"}


P = Player("Random", "Lightning", 15, 10, 100, 100, 0)



gL = True
while gL:
    intro1.printPage()
    intro1.pageInput()
```

OUTPUT Example:

```
  *** Page One ***  
Intro Page
  1 Character Stats
  2 Rename Character
  3 Exit
  4 Home
  5 Change Element
Num: 4
Working home
None
```

Comment: See [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you `print(self.pageOptions[pInput]['entry']())` but all kinds of entries return `None`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used function,

```
def Home():
    print('Working home')
```

But it isn't returning anything it means it return None, so in the line,

```
print(self.pageOptions[pInput]['entry']())
```

it printing None.

So please use,

```
self.pageOptions[pInput]['entry']()
```

It works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's perfect :D

Answer (score 1):

You print the result of “Home()”, but Home does not return a value, so it defaults to None

```
print(self.pageOptions[pInput]['entry']())
...
def Home():
    print('Working home')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your pageInput() function as :

```
def pageInput(self):
    pInput = int(input('Num: '))
    if pInput in self.pageOptions:
        self.pageOptions[pInput]['entry']()
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```